# XCode Local Changes Indicator like other IDEs

Tags: xcode, git, ide

I'm new to XCode and Objective-C programming. I have used WebStorm, IntelliJ, Netbeans, and Eclipse. They all support something like this:

[image: WebStorm stuff]

Notice the colors on the left that indicate what's changed locally. Clicking on those will show me what it was before and allow me to reset the local copy to what it was before. Very useful and I do it all the time.

Obviously, with iOS programming, I want to use XCode, but I really want to have those indicators. All I see with XCode is this:

[image: XCode]

Notice that there's no indicator at all...

**Note:** I am **not** talking about being able to open a git diff tool, even if it's built into XCode. I am looking for the simplicity that all the other IDEs give me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing in Xcode is the version editor. Choose View > Version Editor > Show Version Editor to show the version editor. The version editor shows your local copy and the last committed version of the file side by side and highlights the changes between the two versions.

Comment: Too bad it's not available in the way the other IDEs have it... Thanks for the answer.